# Continuous Loop until Condition is met

Tags: java, loops, sum, average

So I have to create a java project in eclipse for my class. The Assignment is to create a program that will allow the user to enter integers into the program until a certain integer is enter (42). After the integer (42) is entered, the program will then **1**. average all numbers entered. **2**. display the min and max number entered. **3**. Total number of numbers entered. And these have to be calculated without counting the (42). This is what i have so far. I can get input from the user and once they enter 42 the program stops and will display the total but with 42 included. And i'm not sure how i could add in a "count" for the input so i can use the count to display total numbers entered as well as dividing count from sum to give me the average. I appreciate any help.

```
package assignment6;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class assignment6 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Scanner
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Enter integer
        System.out.println("Enter a integer ");
        int data = input.nextInt();

        //Accept integers until 42 is entered
        int sum = 42;
        while (data != 42) {
            sum += data;

            System.out.println("Enter another integer ");
            data = input.nextInt();
        }
        //Display sum of numbers entered
        System.out.println("The sum of all numbers entered is: " + sum);

        //Display Average of numbers entered
        System.out.println("Average of all numbers entered is:" + ( sum/ ));

    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check Below Code.

```
package stackoverflow;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class LoopTest {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter number");

    int input  = 0;
    double sum = 0;
    double avg = 0;
    int count = 0;

    //Infinite Loop
    while (true)
    {   
        //Accept Number
        input  = scanner.nextInt();

        //Check Entered Number
        if (input  != 42)
        {
            sum = sum + input ;
            count = count + 1;
            avg = sum/count;
        }
        else
            break;
    }

    System.out.println("Numbers Entered : " + count);
    System.out.println("Sum of Numbers : " + sum);
    System.out.println("Average of Numbers : " + avg);
}

}
```

Comment: This works perfectly. I should be able to figure out how to display the smallest number entered and largest number entered on my own. I appreciate the help

Comment: add  int min = 0;
  int max = 0;
and  change if block as ---- if (input  != 42)
   {
    if (input < min || min == 0) 
     min = input;
    if (input > max)
     max = input;
    array[count] = input;
    sum = sum + input ;
    count = count + 1;
    avg = sum/count;
   } then display min and max value

Answer (score 0):

if sum is set to 0, you could count the 42.

Also, use `while(true)` to loop forever, and `break;` to end the loop. nothing after the break statment is executed, so

```
int count = 1;
while(true) {
   sum += data;

   System.out.println("Enter another integer ");
   data = input.nextInt();
   count++;
   if(data == 42) {
       break;
   }
}
```

Comment: so i entered that into eclipse and say i run it and enter "10" "10" "10" and "42", the program doesnt go to the next step (sum, average, etc) until you enter another number after 42. The total should be 30 and the average should be 10 because it is divided by three but instead i receive "72 sum" and "18 average".  Does this make sense?

Comment: You are getting 72 because it is like 30 + 42. Hence if you deduct 42 everytime you will get your desired sum and average. This is not the "real" solution but just a suggestion you may want to consider! :D

Answer (score -1):

Well to add a count all you would have to do is make a variable

```
    int count = 0;
```

For example and then just add one to it every time the loop repeats

Comment: Did "Int" successfully compiled for you ?

Comment: @mhasan what do you mean?

Comment: I hope you are aware Java compiler is case sensitive

Comment: @mhasan oh that was just a typo I didn't write that code in eclipse. I just wrote it out here

Comment: Plz make sure run the solution before posting to SO

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class assignment6 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Scanner
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Enter integer
        System.out.println("Enter a integer ");
        int data = input.nextInt();
        int sum   = 0 ;
        int count = 0 ;
        //Accept integers until 42 is entered

        while (data != 42) {
            sum += data;
            count += 1;

            System.out.println("Enter another integer "); 
            data = input.nextInt();
        }
        //Display sum of numbers entered
        System.out.println("The sum of all numbers entered is: " + sum);

        //Display Average of numbers entered
        System.out.println("Average of all numbers entered is:" + ( sum/count ));

    }
}
```